# MVC Application endpoint Authentication Required for subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a `c#.net` `MVC3` application running on `Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter`.

If I deploy the application as an application under the main site (i.e. `www.mysite.com/crm`) it works perfectly.

If I deploy the application as a sub-domain to the main site (i.e. `crm.mysite.com`) it appears to work as expected, with the exception of one endpoint (`crm.mysite.com/reports/view`).  That path returns the following authentication notice:

```
Authentication Required
The server http://crm.mysite.com:80 requires a username and password.
```

I am not aware of anything special for that endpoint and, as I mentioned, it works without issues when deployed under the main site.

What would cause this?  How do I remove/prevent it?

I don't even know what code to provide to help diagnose the problem. Please let me know if you want to see parts of the code for any section related to this issue.

**UPDATE**:

I don't move the path to the application files for either situation and they both use the same application pool.  The only difference is how a user access the files via `IIS`.

**UPDATE2**:

If I authenticate a user, I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/Reports' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

Why would it think the resource doesn't exist when clearly it does?

Answer (score 0):

If you have authentication on the main site, it won't automatically carry authentication across to the sub-domain.  You would have to develop a mechanism to handle that such as SSO (single sign on).

Another potential issue is permissions for the directory/application (eg. `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\crm.mysite.com`)

Comment: The application has authentication, and the user has to authenticate prior to doing ANYTHING.  This means all other views are correctly protected and working, so why is this one endpoint losing that authentication?

Comment: If they are signing on while at www.mysite.com/crm, the authentication cookie won't carry over to crm.mysite.com.  The user would have to re-authenticate.

Comment: I don't change the actual path to the files, only how I access them via IIS.

Comment: all paths for `crm.mysite.com/...` redirect to the login `crm.manex.com/Login`.  Once the user is authenticated, he can access everything except `/Reports/View`

Comment: Are the 2 sites running in the same app pool?  If not, it may be that you have to give the the "new" app pool permissions on the directory.

Comment: I just changed the application pools to match and received the same results.